# How to print duplex with Epson AL-MX200 printer?

Tags: macos, printing, driver, postscript

It can't print both sided as the duplex select on the print window is grayed. It works fine on Linux. How to tell the driver that the printer is an actual duplex printer? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried localized Epson support to see if there is an updated driver? In the US this printer isn't in Epson's list of printers, past or present!

Comment: Yes I tried latest epson driver, but still disabled... :/

Comment: You may want to experiment with [CUPS](https://support.vendhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/205052024-Enabling-CUPS-Printer-Interface-for-Mac) & CUPS [printer drivers](http://www.openprinting.org/drivers).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a driver that may help. https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/epson_al_mx200.html

Comment: i installed vuescan but it's a scan software as I can see and duplex is still disabled if I try to print from Mail for instance. How do you mean that it fixes the problem ?